# PHP-FPM errors only when running as a system service on Fedora 20. (File not found / Primary script not found)

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm, fastcgi, systemd

I am trying to setup NGINX with PHP-FPM on a Fedora 20 box and I am getting the "File not found / Primary script unknown" errors **only** when starting php-fpm as a system service.

I am using a default setup in NGINX with the default fastcgi.conf included.
(Using: `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;`)

Here's the relevant nginx.conf:

```
root   /var/www/index;
index  index.html index.php index.htm;

location ~ \.php$ {
          try_files      $uri = 404; 
          fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
          fastcgi_index  index.php;
          include        fastcgi.conf;
}
```

Now, when I start php-fpm directly from the shell (as root) everything works absolutely fine, however when I start php-fpm using `systemctl start php-fpm.service` I get the "File not found / Primary script unknown" errors.

Here's the php-fpm.service defintion:

```
[Unit]
Description=The PHP FastCGI Process Manager
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=notify
PIDFile=/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.pid
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/php-fpm
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/php-fpm --nodaemonize
ExecReload=/bin/kill -USR2 $MAINPID
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Does anyone have an idea why php-fpm could behave differently when started through systemd?
(I'm very confused especially since php-fpm is spawning worker processes and there shouldn't be any difference between starting from the shell and starting through systemd.)

I am not using any chroot or chdir settings in the fpm pool configuration.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks
Marcus

Comment: In the meantime I found out, that the problem is related to SELinux. When I set SELinux to permissive, php-fpm is starting like it should.

Comment: Well, if you would post some information then we could solve the problem.

Comment: Hi Michael, what information would you need?
(I guess my problem is more that I don't know how to configure SELinux permissions and directives, so I'm not able to set it up properly for php-fpm. I guess that a more experienced user would be able to figure it out. Seems like it's coming down to file access permissions.)